# JavaScript, Typescript switch statement: way to run same code for two cases?

Tags: javascript, typescript, switch-statement

Is there a way to assign two different case values to the same block of code without copy and pasting? For example, below 68 and 40 should execute the same code, while 30 is not related.

```
case 68:
   //Do something
break;

case 40:
   //Do the same thing
break;

case 30:
   //Do something different
break;
```

Is it incorrect to think something like this should work (even though it obviously doesn't)?

```
case 68 || 40:
   //Do something
break;

case 30:
   //Do something else
break;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch statement for multiple cases in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-for-multiple-cases-in-javascript)

Answer (score 235, accepted):

Just put them right after each other without a break

```
switch (myVar) {
  case 68:
  case 40:
    // Do stuff
  break;

  case 30:
    // Do stuff
  break;
}
```

Comment: Sonar finds this as innapropiate, ¿another option?

Comment: @IgnacioAra This question is targetted for Javascript. (although the same code works for C# too)

Comment: @Steven Yes, I know, Sonar is available for many languages (https://www.sonarqube.org/)

Comment: @IgnacioAra I see, I looked up some information about cases and it seems fine using them as exception: https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S128?layout=false

Comment: I see what you mean, I hope they'll fix it soon detecting it as an exception (in Sonar tools). Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Yes, you just put the related `case` statements next to each other, like this:

```
case 40:  // Fallthrough
case 68:
   // Do something
   break;

case 30:
   // Do something different
   break;
```

The `Fallthrough` comment is there for two reasons:

- It reassures human readers that you're doing this deliberately
- It silences warnings from Lint-like tools that issue warnings about possible accidental fallthrough.

Comment: will this be a "and" case or a "or case" if we add multiple cases like this

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "and case".  The value can't be both 40 and 68 at the same time.  If the value is 40 the code will "Do something".  If the value is 68 it will "Do something".  If the value is 30 it will "Do something different".

Answer (score 5):

```
case 68:
case 40:
  // stuff
  break;
```

Answer (score 5):

## Cleaner way to do that

```
if ([68, 48, 22, 53].indexOf(value) > -1)
    //Do something
else if ([44, 1, 0, 24, 22].indexOf(value) > -1)
    //Do another
```

You can do that for multiple values with the same result

Answer (score 0):

[Switch cases can be clubbed as shown in the dig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvTyX.jpg)

Also, It is not limited to just two cases, you can extend it to any no. of cases.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score -16):

You should use:

```
switch condition {
  case 1,2,3:
    // do something
  case 4,5:
    // do something
  default:
    // do something
}
```

Cases should be comma-separated.

Comment: This is simply wrong. You can't have multiple values in a switch case