# Double Pipe in a Switch Case Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a switch case, and I want to direct 3 different possible cases to one outcome using the double pipe.

http://jsfiddle.net/qCA3G/

```
var type = "JPEG"

switch(type){
    case "PNG" || "JPG" || "JPEG":
    alert("works");
    break;
    default:
    alert("not working");
    break;
}
```

The obvious thing to do would be making a separate case for each of the file types, but there must be a more efficient way, that resembles my attempt.

Comment: Read about "switch fallthrough".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch statement multiple cases in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-multiple-cases-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is why switch has fall-through:

```
switch(type){
    case "PNG":
    case "JPG": 
    case "JPEG": 
       alert("works");
       break;
    default:
       alert("not working");
       break;
}
```

But fallthrough is a fickle beast! Beware the dreaded forgotten break statement

```
switch(type){
    case "PNG":
    case "JPG": 
    case "JPEG": 
       alert("works");
    default: // forgot break BOTH ALERTS RUN!
       alert("not working");
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not the way [switch case](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) works. You need to instead create fall-through case'(skipping the break statement).

```
var type = "JPEG"

switch(type){
    case "PNG":  
    case "JPG":  
    case "JPEG":  
       alert("works");
    break; //break here if you dont want to fall through again
    default:
       alert("not working");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is:

```
        var type = "JPEG"

        switch (type) {
        case "PNG":
        case "JPG":
        case "JPEG":
            alert("works");
            break;
        default:
            alert("not working");
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var type = "JPEG"

switch(type){
    case "PNG":
    case "JPG":
    case "JPEG":
      alert("works");
    break;
    default:
      alert("not working");
    break;
}
```