# How to limit cursor

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a private webpage. 
I have a cursor i created from css, and a box also from css to mimic a textfield.
THe reason i don't want to use text field is because of default cursor.

I sucessfully been able to move the cursor with switch statement for keyboard input. Switch because some keys are ignored and do other functions.
I also created a backspace to return cursor to begining.

However, i have a few problems. My text field is 60% width, and i want to limit the cursor to only go to 58.58% to the right, the direction the text is going. When i try to do this using an if else inside the switch statement, and type 3 times a key, the cursor then jumps to the 58.58% mark on end of my created text field. 
How do i stop that. 
And secondly, i want to be able to display characters on the screen in over my text field to mimic a real one. But i cant seem to have any success.

Can anyone help.

My code below for the entire set up. Which hides placeholder text over the box, and allows backspace and type. H
How do i limit cursor, and create character text to go over the box as i type and also allow characters to shift backwards once i reach the end of the text box?

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
var stoppos = $("#cursor").css("left");
switch(e.keyCode){
case 8:

if (stoppos < "10.15%") {
$("#cursor").css("background-color","#0000FF").css("left","0.15%");
$("#commandtext").show();
}   
else {
$("#cursor").css("left","-=15%");
}
break;
case 16:
$("#commandtext").show();
break;

/* Many more switch cases */

case 116:
$("#commandtext").show();
break;
default:            
$("#commandtext").hide();
$("#cursor").css("background-color","#0000FF").css("left","+=15%");
}
```

Comment: Off topic: The repetition in that code sample hurts my brain. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13207939/1264804

Comment: Sorry, THose keys will be doing other functions. Specific functions.

Comment: Why did you wrote the same code over and over again? Just use case fallback.

Comment: You can have multiple `case` statements in a row, which is why you need a `break` statement to prevent fall-through execution.

Comment: Can anyone answer my original question?. Im not concerned about how many switch statements i have.