# JavaScript Switch Statement - Condition in Case

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Can I put a conditional operator in my JS switch statement?

eg. case `n||n`:

eg. case `"string2"||"string1"`:

```js
switch(expression) {
  case n||n:
    code block
    break;
  case n||n:
    code block
    break;
  default:
    default code block
}
```

Comment: Most people will do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-multiple-cases-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a fall-through:

```
switch (expression) {
  case "exp1":
  case "exp2":
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // default code block
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
switch(expression) {
    case n:
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    case n:
    case n:
        code block
        break;
    default:
        default code block
}
```

Basically lay them out one after the other