# How to get multiple strings into one case in Java Script?

Tags: javascript

So I've been using switch statements, and was wondering if there is a way to get several strings into one case, instead of only one string per case.

For example:

```
switch(fruits) {
case 'apples','bananas','oranges','strawberries':

//I'd like to get those four  fruits into one case, instead of doing this:   
switch (fruits) {
    case 'apples':
    break;
    case 'bananas':
    break;
    case 'oranges':
     break;
     case 'strawberries':
```

If this can be done it will save me a lot of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-multiple-cases-in-javascript`

Comment: `if (['apples','bananas','oranges','strawberries'].indexOf(fruits) >= 0 ...`

Comment: I looked through that post and it did not answer how to stuff everything into a single 'case' instead of having to type out 'case' multiple times (one case for each item)

Comment: wait are you testing a string that contains all 4 fruits?

Comment: Edwin, I was wanting to give one 'case' several fruits, instead of having to type them all out separately. Looks like that is not possible with a single 'case' and I was given some alternative answers below.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like:

```
switch (fruits) {
case 'apples':
case 'bananas':
case 'oranges': 
case 'strawberries': 
    //Your code
    break; 
}
```

Comment: That is still using multiple cases. How do I put all the fruits into only one case?

Comment: @EdwardK. [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) is not designed for that. And this will do what you want `//your code` will get executed if any of the above cases is true.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use switch/case when you need multiple value matches. Use `IF`:

```
if(fruits === 'apples'  || 
   fruits === 'bananas' || 
   fruits === 'oranges' || 
   fruits === 'strawberries'){
   //do some action
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid the `switch` altogether: store all the fruits in an array and then use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to see if the fruit is there:

```
var arr = ['apples', 'bananas', 'oranges', 'strawberries'];

function check(arr, fruit) {
    return arr.some(function (el) {
        return el.indexOf(fruit) > -1;
    });
}

if (check(arr, 'oranges') {
    // do stuff if true
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ucso9co3/2/0)