# How do I get my code that uses 'switch' and 'case' to work?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an animation where I have a simple red block which changes to a blue block of the same size if I click a button.
I wrote my code but it doesn't work and I don't know what's wrong with it. I think that it is something to do with the 'switch' and 'case' functions(?(I'm not sure if they're called 'functions')) I was wondering if anyone knew what was wrong.
This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>

function switch1(){
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fill();
}

var status = 0;

function switch2(){
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fill();
}

function backtored(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas")
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        switch(Number(status)){
                ctx.beginPath();
                        ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
                        ctx.fill()
                }

}

function swappy(){
    switch(Number(status)){
        case 0:
            switch1();
                status = 1;
        case 1:
            switch2();
                status = 0;

        }
}


</script> 
<body onload="swappy();backtored()">

<button type="button" onclick="swappy()">Change colour</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

When I run it, there is just a blank box with a button next to it saying "Change colour". Can someone please help and alert me to my mistakes.
Thanks

Comment: You forgot to `break`

Comment: Don't `switch` statements need a `break`?

Comment: See the proper syntax in [Switch statement multiple cases in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13207927/1529630)

Answer (score 2):

You need to `break` in your [switch statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx).

Ex. . .

```
function swappy(){
    switch(Number(status)){
        case 0:
            switch1();
                status = 1;
            break;
        case 1:
            switch2();
                status = 0;
            break;
        }
}
```