# Reducer composition: reducer calling another reducer in only one of its cases, yet working for the rest of them

Tags: redux

guys.
I've been learning redux and there is something about reducers that I haven't been able to fully comprehend.

In [redux docs](http://redux.js.org/), a simple example is provided. 
In the reducers of said example, there is one reducer that calls another reducer.
This is the code for these reducers:

```
function posts(state = {
  isFetching: false,
  didInvalidate: false,
  items: []
}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        didInvalidate: true
      })
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
        didInvalidate: false
      })
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        didInvalidate: false,
        items: action.posts,
        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

function postsBySubreddit(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

As you can see, `postsBySubreddit` calls `posts`. I understand this; it's reducer composition.
What I don't understand is why the `posts` reducer is being called only in the `REQUEST_POSTS` case and not in the rest of them, yet it updates the state properly for the other cases.
My flawed logic tells me that in order for the `postsBySubreddit` to work in all cases, it should employ the same mechanism in the `RECEIVE_POSTS` and the `INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT` cases, as follows:

```
function postsBySubreddit(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
      })
    case RECEIVE_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
      })
    case REQUEST_POSTS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks in advance.
P.D. The full source code for this example can be found [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple switch cases stacked on top of each other they will all run the bottom case's statements.

In this instance

```
case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
case RECEIVE_POSTS:
case REQUEST_POSTS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
  })
```

is identical to

```
case INVALIDATE_SUBREDDIT:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
  })
case RECEIVE_POSTS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
  })
case REQUEST_POSTS:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    [action.subreddit]: posts(state[action.subreddit], action)
  })
```

Comment: Ok, great! Now I get it. Javascrpit's fall-through feature of the of the switch statement, right? [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-multiple-cases-in-javascript ?

Comment: Yep, you got it