# Javascript. Is there an easier way to replace text if certain strings are found?

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, google-sheets

I'm working with Google Sheets Script Editor and I'm trying to do a check to see if a cell contains the text DROPPED, DENIED, WEBSITE, POTENTIAL, SELECTED, TESTING, INACTIVE, or ACTIVE. If it contains DROPPED or DENIED, I need it to say "DENIED", if it says SELECTED/TESTING/INACTIVE/ACTIVE, it needs to say "ACCEPTED", and if it says WEBSITE/POTENTIAL it needs to say "INCOMPLETE".

My code looks roughly like this. I don't have any formal training so it's probably a mess, but hopefully there's an easier way to do it.

```
if (('' + data1[i][1]).trim().toUpperCase() == "DROPPED" ||
    ('' + data1[i][1]).trim().toUpperCase() == "DENIED") {

        sh2.getRange(j + 1, 11, 1, 1).setValue("DENIED"); 

}else if (('' + data1[i][1]).trim().toUpperCase() == "SELECTED" ||
    ('' + data1[i][1]).trim().toUpperCase() == "TESTING" || 
    ('' + data1[i][1].trim().toUpperCase() == "INACTIVE" || 
    ('' + data1[i][1].trim().toUpperCase() == "INACTIVE" ||
    ('' + data1[i][1].trim().toUpperCase() == "ACTIVE") {

        sh2.getRange(j + 1, 11, 1, 1).setValue("ACCEPTED");

}else if (('' + data1[i][1]).trim().toUpperCase() == "WEBSITE" ||
    ('' + data1[i][1]).trim().toUpperCase() == "POTENTIAL") {

        sh2.getRange(j + 1, 11, 1, 1).setValue("INCOMPLETE");
```

I'm pulling this from a "Cross Check" script that's comparing cell contents between two different sheets, which is why it's using `sh2.getRange`. Mostly I'm just wondering if there's an easier way to write it than that huge `if/elseif`. If not, that's fine, it's just going to need to run a couple thousand checks so if I can do it in a way that minimizes the amount of legwork the script does, that would be better.

The only thing I can think of is just forcing the cell to be upper case before it does the checks, and then putting it back to proper case when the checks are done. I don't know if continuing to do `toUpperCase` is going to take more time or not. Honestly I don't know entirely how that even works, I just know it does. We contracted out the original script and I don't know exactly what he did, he didn't comment anything so I had to figure it out myself.

Comment: For starters would be a lot cleaner to read by storing `'' +data1[i][1]).trim().toUpperCase()` in a variable and replacing all instances with that variable

Comment: [Switch statement multiple cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13207939/463206) could be one way.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? As charlie mentions, you definitely want to simplify this by only trimming & uppering once: `var dVal = data[i][1].trim().toUpperCase(); if (dVal === ... ` You can use an `Array#indexOf` method as hinted by Simranjit, or even use an associated object, e.g. `var converter = {DROPPED: "DENIED", DENIED: "DENIED", SELECTED: "ACCEPTED", ... }` and then `var output = converter[dVal]; if (output) { ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sh2.getRange(j + 1, 11, 1, 1).setValue(ParseData(data1[i][1]));


function ParseData(data) {
    switch (('' + data).trim().toUpperCase()) {
        case "SELECTED":
        case "TESTING":
        case "INACTIVE":
        case "ACTIVE":
            {
                return "ACCEPTED";
            }
        case "DROPPED":
        case "DENIED":
            {
                return "DENIED";
            }
        case "WEBSITE":
        case "POTENTIAL":
            {
                return "INCOMPLETE";
            }
        default:
            {
                return "";
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like it would work, I completely forgot about switch statements. It's been like six years since I took a class on this, lol.

Does "parseData(data)" actually work or do I need to replace "data" with something? Or does data become data1[i][1] because it's calling the function up above?

Also, this will all be inside a loop that's incrementing i, will that be a problem? I'm guessing it's best to put the function at the very bottom of the page, after the body function. I think. I'm a bit rusty.

Comment: the names of variables & functions can be changed to any other names in your real project.

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 arrays of groupings
Then you can simply check if value is in one of the arrays then print the respective value.
eg: using one array grouping to get the value denied.

```js
let deniedArray = ['DENIED','DROPPED'];
let value = data1[i][1]).trim().toUpperCase();
if( deniedArray.includes(value) ){
   sh2.getRange(j + 1, 11, 1, 1).setValue("DENIED");
}
```

Comment: Note that Apps Script is JS 1.6 (with some flair), and `Array#includes` is not included.

Comment: then a simple switch case would do as answered by @Dongdong