# Copy or duplicate Page if TextFrame == "Test" exist

Tags: adobe-indesign

In my document which contains a lot of pages i need to Find specific name of text Frame, and if script will find it copy found pages into another document

```
var textFrame = app.activeDocument.textFrames.everyItem().getElements();  
function doesLayerExist(layers, name) {
    for (i=0; i<layers.length; i++) {
        if (layers[i].name==name) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
if (doesLayerExist(app.activeDocument.layers, "SCRIPT")) {
alert("Warstwa Skrypt Istnieje");
if (textFrame[0].contents == "Test")
    {
        alert("Works!");
    }
if (textFrame[0].contents == "Test2")
    {
        alert("Works!");
    }
#......More if statements 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but instead of multiple `If` statements, have you considered using [`Switch`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-multiple-cases-in-javascript)?

Comment: Hi, im not accualy sure how to do it.

Comment: I see the "doesLayerExist" function. I think you need to make a similar function for "doesTextFrameExist"

Comment: Very confusing question. Looking at your description and code, you test against text in the text frame and not its name. What exactly does not work?