# Object based switch alternative in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tend to use expression like this these days:

```
{ typeA: 'some code' }[type] ||
{ typeB: 'some other code' }[type] ||
defaultType
```

How do I fairly simple put multiple cases (something like:

```
switch (value)
{
   case typeA:
   case typeC:
      //do some stuff
      break;
   case typeB:
      //do some other stuff
   default:
       //default stuff
      break;
}
```

) in the code above? So it could work this way (**invalid** piece of code):

```
{ typeA || typeC: 'some code' }[type] ||
{ typeB: 'some other code' }[type] ||
defaultType
```

Backstory: I am utilising the code in React, so the 'some code' samples are actually React components.

Comment: Could you add information on what you are trying to acheive in the first statement of your question ?  ( `{ typeA: 'some code' ...` )

Comment: That should work because of fall through until it hits a break. Is the a specific error you're getting? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-multiple-cases-in-javascript

Comment: Hey @BrettGregson. There's no error. I am just looking for an option to do multiple cases just like the 'switch' does (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13207939/12085047)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could combine the objects into a single one, the first one at last, to keep the values from the first and take `type` as accessor.

For using an alias, you need to specify a new property for it.

```
result = { ...objectB, ...objectA, typeC: objectA.typeA }[type] || defaultValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're halfway there already. Just combine your objects into a big one:

```js
    return ({
        typeA: "Foo",
        typeB: "Bar",
        get typeC() {//why not getters?
            return "computed value"
        }, 
    }[value]) || defaultValue;
```

I strongly recommend saving the case-object as a const or it'll re-allocate on every call.

---

This structure is suitable for values, but not conditional logic. If you need to execute different code on each `case`, you should either stick with `switch`, or make your object return functions:

```js
const Values = {
    caseA: () => { /*...*/ },
    caseB: () => { /*...*/ },
   // ...etc
}


//get value from Values and execute function
Values['caseA']();
```

With this structure you don't get fall-through. If you want fall-through, stick with `switch`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'I strongly recommend saving the case-object as a const or it'll re-allocate on every call.'?

Comment: @user0101 Easier to show with an example. This is code I wrote many years ago: `function doSwitch(foo) { return {foo:"",bar:""}[foo]}`. Every time I invoke `doSwitch`, a new object is allocated. If I did it like that, the `vals` object will allocate once: `const vals = {/*...*/}; function doSwitch(foo) {return vals[foo]}`. Don't worry too much about it, make sure it works first, then you can externalise it

Answer (score 0):

Define your switch-like object:

```
const types = {
  typeA: 'some code',
  ...
}
```

Then call it:

```
types[type] || defaultType
```

You can also include the default value in the switch-lick object:

```
const types= {
  typeA: 'some code',
  ...,
  default: 'some code for default type',
}
```

Later:

```
types[type] || types.default
```

If you are using functions as values:

```
(types[type] && types[type](args)) || types.default()
```