# Array as case in switch case JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How can I use an array as case parameter in switch case?

```
switch ("value")
  case ArrayOfStrings // check every array item to be match with value
    ...
```

Comment: Do you want to check if a *specific* array is passed or if the array constructor function is passed? The former is not possible in a `switch`, the latter is possible but rather odd.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed example of what you are trying to achieve, such as an example of what `...` might be? Is the `Array` in your example literally the `Array` type, so you are wanting to switch on the type?

Comment: do yoi have a use case for it? what about the other cases?

Comment: What is the input for your switch? Is that an array, or are you trying to match one value against an array of values?

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-multiple-cases-in-javascript) what you are looking for?

Comment: what is in the other cases?

Comment: Clean is quite subjective. I find that way very clean. Maybe your solution would be to _not_ use a switch statement, but you haven't provided enough detail for us to determine that. This looks a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

This

> ```
> switch ("value") {
> ```

```
  case ArrayOfStrings // check every array item to be match with value
    ...
```

does not work, because the value of [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) and the value of `case` is checked with a [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) comparison.

It is not possible to check a value agains a value of the array.

Any other construction, like

```
switch (true) {
  case ArrayOfStrings.includes("value"):  // check every array item to be match with value
```

would work, but if you have only to check a single value and not other constraints, you better take

```
if (ArrayOfStrings.includes("value")) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a workaround using find :

```js
const CARS = ['RENAULT', 'FORD']
const SUV = ['PORSCHE', 'LAMBUGININININ']
const SCOOTER = ['HONDA']

function select(vehicule) {
  switch (vehicule) {
    // Alternative use `case undefined: return 'precatch undefined`'
    case vehicule !== undefined && CARS.find(_ => _ === vehicule): return 'CARS';
    case vehicule !== undefined && SUV.find(_ => _ === vehicule): return 'SUV'
    case vehicule !== undefined && SCOOTER.find(_ => _ === vehicule): return 'SCOOTER';
    default: return 'noop';
  }
}

['', null, undefined, 'WHATEVER', 'HONDA', 'RENAULT']
  .forEach(_ => console.log(_, ' - ', select(_)))

/**
Expected result:

  -  noop
null  -  noop
undefined  -  noop
WHATEVER  -  noop
HONDA  -  SCOOTER
RENAULT  -  CARS
**/
```

Not sure how this method is discouraged but sounds not so bad.

Answer (score -2):

Well first I would suggest using `if` with something like `Array.isArray`:

```
if (Array.isArray(value)) {
  // check array items
}
```

But, if you really want/need to check by comparing to `Array` constructor:

```
const check = (value) => {
  switch (value.constructor) {
    case Array:
      console.log('array');
      break;

    // For example
    case Number:
      console.log('number');
      break;
  }
}

check(7); // 'number'
check([]); // 'array'
```

I would really discourage from using this approach though.

Answer (score -3):

In theory, you could do that to distinguish between different constructors.

```
class ArrayOfStrings extends Array<string> {};
class ArrayOfNumbers extends Array<number> {};

function main(input: ArrayOfStrings | ArrayOfNumbers): void {
  switch (input.constructor) {
    case ArrayOfStrings:
      console.log('It was an array of strings!');
      break;
    default:
       console.log('It was something else');
  }
}

main(new ArrayOfStrings('foo', 'bar')); // Logs 'It was an array of strings!'
main(new ArrayOfNumbers(1, 2)); // Logs 'It was something else'
```

However, [this method has limitations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38373).

1. It doesn't work with subclassing.
2. `input` will be of the same type for each `case` — as opposed to being discriminated. See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/en/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCBO8wE8DyAzAygF3gSwDsBzGAUwA9tSCATGBJZAHgl0KID5oBvAXwG4AsAChQkeohQYAcgFcAtgCNS8MpWp04k5gQXL4XPkOEj0sgsGx4A9gWjywhABSEADrOwAuLYww58xDAAPj5S6HJKKhAAlN4AbtZ4NDwi0NAQAO542MAAFtAuBO7YAHTAtqzwspbW8NEpwmlpwJCkoWhYbIGeqU3NFdYgpCUg1kROAOQAktjQGZDQYHZg2tDW6OldJACEE9HGfWluHvzQAPRn0ACi5K6klqTJDGH%207BAANNBE1rPPHa%20BaAhP4yPRRXp9RTwUhgADWByaNFI6DAshAXghfXKBAgg2Go3G01m8xguPkpGwuXY0FIIAgpD2CN4ImZJmEDmcBFIGXafi2EEm6Gs1gmnwmihWe32Ig5BCcXJ5IPCYNUTgAjJ8AEzRaXCIA).
3. You need to create your arrays by using the `new` keyword.

It's better to use `if` statements combined with type guards instead.