# Listen for multiple commands in a case

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to get it so that when a user says a command like '!help' or '!commands' it returns the help message, in order to save space in my code and not use 2 cases, how can I make this into 1?

```
client.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");

    switch (args[0]) {

        case ('help' || 'commands'):
```

I'm not sure what to do, it responds to "help" but not to commands. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch statement multiple cases in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207927/switch-statement-multiple-cases-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `switch` statement has a feature where you can create an empty `case`. If the `case` returns true, it will simply execute the next `case` statement with code.

```js
switch ('someString') {
  case 'someString':
  case 'someOtherString': {
      console.log('This will still execute');
      break;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should not do, is use a `switch` to handle your commands in the first place.

What you should do is use a command handler. That way you can export all your commands into seperate files and use something called `aliases`.

Start with creating a `commands` folder in the same directory as your `index.js`. Each file needs to be a `.js` file with the following content.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'your command name', // needs to be completly lowercase
    aliases: ["all", "of", "your", "aliases"],
    description: 'Your description',
    execute: (message, args) => {
        // the rest of your code
    }
}
```

Next you need to add some things to your `index.js` file.
Require the file system module `fs` and `Discord`. Create two new Collections.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
client.aliases = new Discord.Collection();
```

---

Next you need to add all of the names and aliases to your two new Collections.

```
// Read all files in the commands folder and that ends in .js
const commands = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
// Loop over the commands, and add all of them to a collection
// If there's no name found, prevent it from returning an error
for (let file of commands) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    // Check if the command has both a name and a description
    if (command.name && command.description) {

        client.commands.set(command.name, command);

    } else {
        console.log("A file is missing something")
    }
    
    // check if there is an alias and if that alias is an array
    if (command.aliases && Array.isArray(command.aliases))
        command.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, command.name));
};
```

---

Now that we added all of our commands to the collection we need build our command handler in `client.on('message', message {...})`.

```
client.on('message', message => {
    // check if the message comes through a DM
    //console.log(message.guild)
    if (message.guild === null) {
        return message.reply("Hey there, no reason to DM me anything. I won't answer anyway :wink:");
    }
    // check if the author is a bot
    if (message.author.bot) return;    
    // set a prefix and check if the message starts with it
    const prefix = "!";
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        return;
    }
    // slice off the prefix and convert the rest of the message into an array
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);    
    // convert all arguments to lowercase
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();
    // check if there is a message after the prefix
    if (cmd.length === 0) return;
    // look for the specified command in the collection of commands
    let command = client.commands.get(cmd);
    // If no command is found check the aliases
    if (!command) command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(cmd));
    // if there is no command we return with an error message
    if (!command) return message.reply(`\`${prefix + cmd}\` doesn't exist!`);
    // finally run the command
    command.execute(message, args);
});
```

[This](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#individual-command-files) is a guide without the aliases key.