# Discord.js bot doesn't come online hosted with Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I am having trouble hosting my bot on heroku. I have already deployed my bot and it worked for about 30 hours or so. I then turned off my bot for about 10 hours and made some MAJOR changes to my code. However, the config.json and Procfile files remained the same. I have tried multiple things such as restart the worker.1 dyno. I also deleted my app and recreated it. Someone said to change `worker: node index.js` to `worker: npm start` or `service: npm start`. Both didn't work.

Procfile : `service: npm start`

Config.json :

```
{
    "mongoPath": "mongodb://localhost:27017",
    "useNewUrlParser": "true",
    "prefix": "$",
    "token": "MY SUPER SECRET TOKEN"
}
```

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "discord-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" $$ exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": " "
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Joel",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.3",
    "discord.js": "^12.4.1",
    "discord.js-tictactoe": "^1.0.2",
    "humanize-duration": "^3.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.11",
    "ms": "^2.1.2",
    "opusscript": "0.0.7",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "wokcommands": "^1.0.1",
    "ytdl-core": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.4.0",
    "npm": "6.14.5"
  }
}
```

Index.js

```
//Packages
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const ms = require('ms');
const fs = require('fs');
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
const Duration = require('humanize-duration');
const config = require('./config.json');


//clients
const bot = new Discord.Client();
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const Embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
bot.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    bot.commands.set(command.name, command);
}


bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('ACTIVE!');
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    let args = message.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(' ');
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'ban') {
        bot.commands.get('pp').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'members') {
        bot.commands.get('pp').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'cls') {
        bot.commands.get('cls').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'ctc') {
        bot.commands.get('ctc').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'cvc') {
        bot.commands.get('cvc').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'echo') {
        bot.commands.get('echo').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'g') {
        bot.commands.get('g').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'gg') {
        bot.commands.get('gg').execute(message, args, bot, Discord, Duration);
    } else if (command === 'help') {
        bot.commands.get('help').execute(message, args, Discord, Duration);
    } else if (command === 'i') {
        bot.commands.get('i').execute(message, args, cheerio);
    } else if (command === 'iq') {
        bot.commands.get('iq').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'kick') {
        bot.commands.get('kick').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'members') {
        bot.commands.get('members').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'pick') {
        bot.commands.get('pick').execute(message, args, bot, Discord);
    } else if (command === 'ping') {
        bot.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'pl') {
        bot.commands.get('pl').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'pm') {
        bot.commands.get('pm').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'poll') {
        bot.commands.get('poll').execute(message, args, Embed);
    } else if (command === 'pp') {
        bot.commands.get('pp').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'spam') {
        bot.commands.get('spam').execute(message, args, bot);
    } else if (command === 'status') {
        bot.commands.get('status').execute(message, args, bot);
    } 
});

bot.login(config.token);
```

Logs :

```
2020-11-04T22:11:10.210494+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-11-04T22:11:10.927608+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-11-04T22:11:13.224071+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-11-04T22:11:13.224087+00:00 app[worker.1]: > discord-bot@1.0.0 start /app
2020-11-04T22:11:13.224087+00:00 app[worker.1]: > node index.js
2020-11-04T22:11:13.224088+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2020-11-04T22:11:14.157433+00:00 app[worker.1]: ACTIVE!
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean "not online"? Do you mean the status in discord because your log indicates it does work.

Comment: also, please regenerate your discord token!

Comment: yes, i mean the status. But i also mean that none of the commands work. However, if i run this locally all the commands work.

Comment: yes, i already have regenerated it

Comment: you can manually set the status if that is what you're concerned with. You mentioned that you made major changes, can you include whats in your `onMessage` handler? Maybe something in there is preventing the commands.

Comment: I have added the code in my onMessage

Comment: mmh, code looks ok. [Command handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323174/listen-for-multiple-commands-in-a-case/64323715#64323715) could use some love but it should work. The fact that your heroku log looks fine is weird. Are you sure you don't get any errors what so ever?

Comment: 100% sure. If you want i can take a video of what happens. The weird part is, the bot never comes online. In my server it is just seen as offline. And none of the commands work.

Comment: Any you're sure that `worker: npm start` doesn't do anything? You can try to manually set it online with the [`setPresence`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=setPresence) method. What you could also try is a `console.log(message)` at the top of your `onMessage` event to see if it actually reads the messages.

Comment: Hmmmm... Let me try that.

Comment: Ok, so i tried to run it locally and now it doesnt work loacally too which is suuuuuper weird since it was working loacally over 5 horus ago

Comment: Thus is getting stranger and stranger. Do you get any errors now? Locally or on heroku.

Comment: Nope no errors at all

Comment: @WorthyAlpaca do you know anyone who would be able to help me in this situation. Because i have literally tried everything. Kicking my bot. Deleting my app from heroku and remaking it. Console logging everything. Everything checks out except for the fact that the message callback doesnt work.

Comment: Not a solution but please fix your if else if chain to a dynamic function executer because thats a pain in the ass to look at.

Comment: im new to js, could you please let me know what a dynamic function executer is?

Comment: Basically it's a way to execute your commands without having to add them to a file all manually. See the link in my comment above. But that's not important to your situation as your code works.

Comment: Just a quick note @WorthyAlpaca i have created a new bot for testing and literally copied and pasted the same code from the bot that isn't working, and it comes online and works like a charm.

Comment: on heroku or your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I fixed it. I regened the token again and it worked.